# CookieAuthenticationOptions, custom action on logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have a following piece of code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never,
            CookieHttpOnly = false,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
```

What I'm trying to do is to perform an action (logging some information to db) on cookie expiration, thus logging out of a user. I was trying to achieve this through LogoutPath, but I realized it does not do what I was expecting ...

Is there a way to inject an action when the cookie expires?

Comment: Is Session_End in global asax still a thing in newer MVC projects?

Comment: I don't think so ... https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/20

Comment: Expired cookies are removed by the client's browser, they are not sent to the server.

Comment: Makes sense - could there possibly be a simple way in the Authentication settings that would allow me to track this? I don't feel like coding something that would monitor users' sessions and activity ...